# Hold a color of Button and use it with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In android I have a three buttons `yes no maybe` here the button get colour changed when its clicked by user and it will stored as 1 0 2 based on the button clicked by user. Here if I closed or just do something in and return back that button it doesn't get color changed. It appears as normal. How to hold that color when we return back to the app

This is the code for `yes no maybe` button

```
yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // highlight the button when clicked
                        yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If user clicks yes button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 1 for event user
                        final int response = 1;
                        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
                        userMO.setIsAttending(response);

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);

                    }

                });
                noBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If user clicks no button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 0 for event user
                        final int response = 0;
                        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
                        userMO.setIsAttending(response);

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                    }
                });
                maybeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If user clicks maybe button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as  for event user
                        final int response = 2;
                        userMO.setIsAttending(response);
                        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                    }
                });
```

This `yes no maybe` button shows when `event` is clicked
`event` is a list view. This `yes no maybe` response layout shows when clicked any event in that list view

Here how to use shared preference if I used shared preference like following under the yes button

`SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();`

It shows error on `cannot resolve method getSharedPreferences`

Comment: * Declare some flag for each color, and store as string value in sharedpreference. Then retrieve the preference value each time you login and set that perticular color based on flag.

Comment: you can use onSavedInstanceState to save primitive data types very effectively and retreive them on restoreinstancestate and change the color of your buttons accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Simply save in the Sharedprefrences whether you clicked the button or not.
And put this code inside onClick the button

```
SharedPreference sharedpreferences prefs =   
getSharedPreferences("UI_Elements", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor editor = prefs.edit;
editor.putString("buttonClicked","true");
editor.commit();
```

Now you need to check in the onCreate() whether your button is clicked or not.
check the the value as

```
if(prefs.getString("buttonClicked","false").equals("true")){
```

// whatever color you want to give after clicking the button give here.

```
yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> sharedpreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

You probably trying to to get it without context. 
If from fragment try: `getActivity().getSharedPreferences()`

Comment: and what is more class name is SharedPreferences, not sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

How to use SharedPreferences:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    //Example
    saveInSharedPrefs("FootballClub", "Manchester United");

    String readResult = readFromSharedPrefs("FootballClub");

    System.out.println(readResult);
}
```

Saving in sharedPreferences:

```
public void saveInSharedPrefs(String name, String save){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putString(name, save);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Read from sharedPreferences:

```
public String readFromSharedPrefs(String name){
    return sharedPref.getString(name, "Default value");
}
```

Now you just have to save the color and recreate it when reading.